# D3.js Visualization: Graph with weighted nodes and labelled edges

Tags: javascript, d3.js, graph, rdf, visualization

First I have to say I'm an absolute beginner with D3.js.

I was searching the web for a long time, but couldn't find any matching solution.

I want to read a JSON file with subjects, predicates and objects. Mostly like RDF, but the nodes (subjects & objects) have a weight, so I want them to appear in different sizes.

Also it would be nice to have some kind of interactivity: the labelled attribute of the edge (predicate) should only be visible, when I zoom in or click on it. Also, a popup with further information would be nice, if I click on a node.

I'm looking for the most lightweight solution, but would be happy about any approach!

Comment: This is probably too broad for a Stack Overflow question.  Once you've got a specific programming problem, it will make for a better question.  That said, having worked a lot with RDF and having done a fair amount with D3, I think you'll find the [force layout](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Force-Layout) useful for displaying the graph (it's easy enough to control the radius of the nodes), The rest is probably just adding event handlers for the actions that you're interested in.  The nodes in the graph are just SVG elements in the DOM, so you get event handlers for free.

Comment: Also, and I don't mean to be snarky here, but what did you search for and try before you posted this question (i.e., what's the "research effort")?  A [Google search for "visualize rdf with d3"](https://goo.gl/7HPlMJ) turns up [Visual RDF](http://graves.cl/visualRDF/?url=http://graves.cl/visualRDF/) which already seems to have a lot of what you're looking for ([GitHub page](https://github.com/alangrafu/visualRDF)), and the Google results seem to include a number of other useful links, too.